# Find textarea and replace with something else

Tags: php, regex

```
<html>
<head><title>Example page</title></head>
<body>
<textarea name="description">This is some text</textarea>
<input type='text' name='bla' value='a textinput' />
<textarea name="interests">What i like to do</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

The above html code is the value of a variable. I want to grab all the textareas and replace them by something. What would be the way to get following array from the string:

```
1: <textarea name="description">This is some text</textarea>
2: <textarea name="interests">What i like to do</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`DOMDocument->loadHTML()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load the HTML as a DOM tree,
2. Find the `textarea` elements (and their text nodes)
3. Replace with relevant element.

Cf. [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

---

**In essence**: avoid regular expressions for this kind of tasks. If you *insist* (and the HTML is guaranteed to be as simple as indicated), try:

```
preg_replace('/<textarea name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/textarea>/', '<input type="text" name="\\1" value="\\2">', $yourHtmlString);
```

([demo](http://www.ideone.com/5DJ0n))